Styling issue using react-spring and nextjs
I am trying to animate transitions using between pages on an app using react-spring and nextjs using a toggle that lives in _app.tsx. For some reason when the transition happens, there is a space between the loaded component that renders while it is transitioning, and then jumps back when the transition is complete. Would love some help figuring out why this is happening.
Gif of behaviour: https://imgur.com/a/4nwHNmv
_app.tsx:
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useTransition, animated, useIsomorphicLayoutEffect } from "react-spring";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import { Segmented } from "antd";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";

const geistSans = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/GeistVF.woff",
  variable: "--font-geist-sans",
  weight: "100 900",
});
const geistMono = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/GeistMonoVF.woff",
  variable: "--font-geist-mono",
  weight: "100 900",
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const [componentArray, setComponentArray] = useState([
    <Component key={pathname} {...pageProps} />,
  ]);

  console.log(componentArray);

  const transitions = useTransition(componentArray, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(100%,0,0)" },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: "translate3d(0%,0,0)" },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(-50%,0,0)" },
  });

  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (componentArray[0].key === pathname) {
      return;
    }
    setComponentArray([<Component key={pathname} {...pageProps} />]);
  }, [Component, pageProps, router, componentArray]);

  const handleSegmentChange = (value: string) => {
    if (value === "Record") {
      router.push("/record");
    } else if (value === "Replay") {
      router.push("/replay");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles.page} ${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable}`}
    >
      <main className={styles.main}>
          <Segmented
            options={["Record", "Replay"]}
            onChange={handleSegmentChange}
            block={true}
          value={pathname === "/record" ? "Record" : "Replay"}
          style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
        />
        {transitions((style, item) => (
            <animated.div style={{ ...style, width: "100%" }}>
              {item}
            </animated.div>
          ))}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

I suspected that this was a styling issue so I removed everything and still was the same behaviour. I have tried using both useEffect, and useIsomorphicLayoutEffect.
